# get values for potentially multiple matches from an other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill the 'references' column in df_out with the 'ID' if the corresponding 'my_ID' in df_sp is contained in df_jira 'reference_ids'.

```
import pandas as pd

d_sp = {'ID': [1,2,3,4], 'my_ID': ["my_123", "my_234", "my_345", "my_456"], 'references':["","","2",""]}
df_sp = pd.DataFrame(data=d_sp)

d_jira = {'my_ID': ["my_124", "my_235", "my_346"], 'reference_ids': ["my_123, my_234", "", "my_345"]}
df_jira = pd.DataFrame(data=d_jira)

df_new = df_jira[~df_jira["my_ID"].isin(df_sp["my_ID"])].copy()

df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_sp.columns)
needed_cols = list(set(df_sp.columns).intersection(df_new.columns))
for column in needed_cols:
    df_out[column] = df_new[column]
df_out['Related elements_my'] = df_jira['reference_ids']
```

Desired output `df_out`:

```
| ID | my_ID | references |
|----|-------|------------|
|    | my_124|       1, 2 |
|    | my_235|            |
|    | my_346|          3 |
```

What I tried so far is list comprehension, but I only managed to get the reference_ids "copied" from a helper column to my 'references' column with this:

```
for row, entry in df_out.iterrows():
    cpl_ids = [x for x in entry['Related elements_my'].split(', ') if any(vh_id == x for vh_id in df_cpl_list['my-ID'])]
    df_out.at[row, 'Related elements'] = ', '.join(cpl_ids)
```

I can not wrap my head around on how to get the specific 'ID's on the matches of 'any()' or if this actually the way to go as I need *all* the matches, not something if there is *any* match.
Any hints are appreciated!

I work with python 3.9.4 on Windows (adding in case python 3.10 has any other solution)

Backstory: Moving data from Jira to MS SharePoint lists. (Therefore, the 'ID' does not equal the actual index in the dataframe, but is rather assigned by SharePoint upon insertion into the list. Hence, empty after running for the new entries.)

Comment: your desired `df_out` doesn't have the col `Related elements_my` which is the last row in your code. How does that fit together ?

Comment: see the last line in the first code block: df_out['Related elements_my'] = df_jira['reference_ids']

Comment: yes, that was exactly why I was asking. the table of desired output compared with the given code doesn't fit together.... but nvm you got a good solution by MoRe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ref_df = df_sp[["ID","my_ID"]].set_index("my_ID")
df_out.references = df_out["Related elements_my"].apply(lambda x: ",".join(list(map(lambda y: "" if y == "" else str(ref_df.loc[y.strip()].ID), x.split(",")))))
df_out[["ID","my_ID","references"]]
```

output:

```
    ID  my_ID   references
0   NaN my_124  1,2
1   NaN my_235  
2   NaN my_346  3
```

what is `map`?
`map` is something like `[func(i) for i in lst]` and apply `func` on all variables of `lst` but in another manner that increase speed.

and you can read more about this: https://realpython.com/python-map-function/

but, there, our function is : `lambda y: "" if y == "" else str(ref_df.loc[y.strip()].ID)`
so, if y, or y.strip() there and just for remove spaces, is empty, maps to empty: `"" if y == ""` like `my_234`

otherwise, locate `y` in `df_out` and get corresponding ID, i.e maps each `my_ID` to `ID`

hope to be helpfull :)

Comment: works as intended thank you very much! I just have two question for the understanding the HOW :) 1) What does map() help us achieve here? 2) Am I assuming correctly that the .strip() is there to get rid of any left whitespaces after the ','s?

Comment: @GergoPeltz don't mention it :) and 1) I edited my answer, just now 2) yes, exactly

Comment: gotcha, appreciate the added explanation!